# Save the mathematica notebook on cloud as PDF on System/Cloud

Tags: files-and-directories, wolfram-cloud, pdf-format, mathematica-online, save

I am using mathematica on the free Wolfram cloud version.

I first tried using the option of "Print to PDF" available under the "File" on the top of Nav Bar. However, it redirects me to a new tab where this error message is displayed -

```
{"errorCode":"Printed pdf generation failed for + f282dc05620a4a1f899c582a2028039f, with export result: null"}
```

After running this code (which I found their documentation site for saving PDFs) `Export["mynotebook.pdf", EvaluationNotebook[]]`. I am getting the following output, and when I click on "Open", it redirects me to another where it displays the page URL is incorrect and throws me this error
`HTTP Error Code 404`
[image: Output of this code]

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! I have an academic license and a Basic Wolfram Cloud plan, and I can do "Print to PDF" without any problems. It might be that this is somehow not allowed in the free version? As for using `Export`, please try the following code instead: `Export[CloudObject["mynotebook.pdf"], EvaluationNotebook[], "PDF"]`. Please let us know if this works :)

Comment: @Domen, yes, this works! Thank you!